# Jacoco Test coverage report shows 0%

Tags: java, maven, jbehave, jacoco

I have to get the code coverage of a application while business test are executed from a different code base.

I use: Maven as my build
Jbehave as my testing framework.
The test are written in java.

My application is a set of war files deployed on tomcat.

The application code base is separate from test code base.

In getting the coverage I followed the below steps.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rowG.png) Compile the test code using maven.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdvJU.png) Copy application classes from the place it was build (${app.code.dir}/target/classes) to ${test.code.dir}/target/classes

[3] Run the tests and jacoco report through maven

The mvn build: I have kept

```
<profile>
        <id>coverage</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-coverage.exec</destFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com/mytest/bdt/**</exclude><!-- test classes -->
                                    <exclude>com/mytest/bdd/**</exclude><!-- test classes -->
                                </excludes>

                                <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-coverage.exec</dataFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

The jbehave test are executed using :

```
    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
         <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jbehave.core.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>embeddable-stories</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${embeddables5}</include><!--  TestSuite.java -->
                        </includes>
                        <excludes />
                        <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
                        <ignoreFailureInView>true</ignoreFailureInView>
                        <threads>1</threads>
                        <metaFilters>
                            <metaFilter>${meta.filter}</metaFilter>
                            <metaFilter>-skip *</metaFilter>
                            <metaFilter>+run</metaFilter>
                        </metaFilters>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I execute mvn mvn install -Pcoverage

The execution goes as follows.

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] --- jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5:unpack-view-resources (unpack-view-resources) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.3.201306030806:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/testUser/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.3.201306030806/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.3.201306030806-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/testUser/testProj/trunk/target/jacoco-coverage.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.1:compile (default-compile) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/testUser/testProj/trunk/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/testUser/testProj/trunk/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5:run-stories-as-embeddables (embeddable-stories) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] Running stories as embeddables using embedder Embedder[ .....

.....
.....
Test execution log comes here .......
.....
.....

[INFO] Reports view generated with 1 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 25 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
[INFO] Meta filters excluded 0 stories and  24 scenarios
[WARNING] Failures in reports view: 0 scenarios failed
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/testUser/testProj/trunk/target/test-bdd-testsuite-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.3.201306030806:report (default-report) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ test-bdd-testsuite ---
[INFO] Installing /home/testUser/testProj/trunk/target/test-bdd-testsuite-1.0.jar to /home/testUser/.m2/repository/com/testCode/bdd/test-bdd-testsuite/1.0/test-bdd-testsuite-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/testUser/testProj/trunk/pom.xml to /home/testUser/.m2/repository/com/testCode/bdd/test-bdd-testsuite/1.0/test-bdd-testsuite-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.134s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 26 19:18:28 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With this I get a coverage report generated with the application packages. But the coverage is shown as 0%

In the session link the application classes are not loaded.
Screenshots:

Can some one help me here?

Comment: I was  able to resolve this as follows.

Comment: [1] Copyu the application clases in to a instrmentation floder.
  [2] Start the app server (tomcat in mycase) with java arguments "-javaagent:$WORKSPACE/target/lib/jacoco-agent-0.6.3.2.jar=includes=*,destfile=$TOMCAT_HOME/jacoco-coverage.exec,append=false" (I had the jacoco-agent jar copied in to my project at the layout)
  [3] Execute the tests (This can be automated or manual)
  [4] Stopm the tomcat servere (jacoco-coverage.exec is updated at this point)
  [5] Execute ant report target. pointig the updated jacoco-coverage.exec and  copied application class folder.

Comment: Reference:
  
  http://car-online.fr/en/blog/fabien_duchene/2013-05-03-Java%20Code%20Coverage%20in%20Tomcat%20JSP%20applications,%20e.g.,%20WebGoat%20with%20Jacoco/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this as follows

1. Copy the application classes in to a instrumentation folder.
2. Start the app server (tomcat in mycase) with Java arguments

   ```
   -javaagent:$WORKSPACE/target/lib/jacoco-agent-0.6.3.2.jar=includes=*,destfile=$‌​TOMCAT_HOME/jacoco-coverage.exec,append=false
   ```

   (I had the jacoco-agent jar copied in to my project at the layout)
3. Execute the tests (this can be automated or manual)
4. Stop the tomcat server (`jacoco-coverage.exec` is updated at this point)
5. Execute ant report target. pointing the updated jacoco-coverage.exec and copied application class folder.

Reference: http://car-online.fr/en/blog/fabien_duchene/2013-05-03-Java%20Code%20Coverage%20in%20Tomcat%20JSP%20applications,%20e.g.,%20WebGoat%20with%20Jacoco/

Thanks @jens-schauder for pointing me to post this as the answer.